# Action not picked up after import into redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my very first project in React. After picking up a training from Udemy I have achieved upto the following code but stuck at hooking the action into the container (Container is correct?)

Below is what I compiled from different code snippets... I can get the component rendered in the parent and when I hit the Login button, handleFormSubmit runs and logs the username & password into the console. But it seems like I have yet to figure out how my action is to be implanted into props. Any help most appreciated.

First the error message from console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.loginUser is not a function
at Login.handleFormSubmit (bundle.js:49715)
```

login form (`/src/components/auth/login.js`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
import * as actions from '../../actions/index';

const required = value => value==null ?'Required': undefined;

class Login extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit({username, password}) {
    console.log(username, password);

    this.props.loginUser({username, password});
  }

  render () {
    const {handleSubmit, fields: {username, password }} = this.props;


    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <Field {...username}
             name="username"
             validate={required}
             component={TextField}
             hintText="Username"/><br />
      <Field {...password} name="password"
             validate={required}
             component={TextField}
             hintText="Password"
             type="password"/><br />
      <RaisedButton
             primary
             type="submit"
             label="Login"/>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  fields: ['username', 'password'],
}, null, actions)(Login)
```

then I have my actions (`/src/actions/index.js`) as here:

```
import * as constants from '../config/constants';
import axios from 'axios';

export function loginUser({username, password}) {

  return function (dispatch) {

    // Submit details to server
    axios.post(`${constants.ROOT_URL}/login`, { username, password});


    // if good request
    // - update authenticated state
    // - save JWT token
    // - redirect to the route

    // if bad request
    // - show error

  }
}
```

and the third file I am using here are constants (`/src/config/constants.js`)

```
export const ROOT_URL = 'http://x.x.x.x/api';
```

Are you good at React & Redux? Pls help :)

**EDITED - FOLLOWING IS WHAT FINALLY WORKED. Error was due to code usage from older version of React**

login form (`/src/components/auth/login.js`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
import {loginUser} from '../../actions/index';


const required = value => value==null ?'Required': undefined;

class Login extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit({username, password}) {
    console.log(username, password);

    this.props.loginUser({username, password});
  }

  render () {
    const {handleSubmit, fields: {username, password }} = this.props;


    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <Field {...username}
             name="username"
             validate={required}
             component={TextField}
             hintText="Username"/><br />
      <Field {...password} name="password"
             validate={required}
             component={TextField}
             hintText="Password"
             type="password"/><br />
      <RaisedButton
             primary
             type="submit"
             label="Login"/>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

Login = reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  fields: ['username', 'password'],
})(Login)

export default Login = connect(null, {loginUser} )(Login)
```

Comment: what are you passing to your Login component? it doesn't look like you are passing any?

Comment: instead of `this.props.loginUser` i guess what you want is `actions.loginUser`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access your loginForm function from your props on line 13:

`this.props.loginUser`

but you are actually importing it on line 5 under actions. So instead line 13 should look like

`actions.loginUser`

Comment: no problem. please check it as a selected answer / correct answer if it helped!

Comment: Have to wait 3 more mins :)

Comment: hehe well no rush :)

Comment: Problem 2: loginUser is not firing. Console log of "actions.loginUser({...})" is returning the function itself but not firing a network call.

Comment: that's because `loginUser` returns a function that you have to call.